# Take a picture and get bytes without saving on disk

Tags: android, android-camera, android-image, android-image-capture

Is it possible to take a picture and get the image as byte array without saving it?

All I want is, take an in memory picture. I don't want to save it. Also i plan to use other camera activity to take the picture (i mean, i don't want to implement my own camera logic)

Please note, I know that I can take a picture, read bytes and delete it. But I am looking if I can avoid this saving and deleting part, instead directly get the image in an in memory byte array.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to take a picture and get the image as byte array without saving it?

That is the behavior of the `android.hardware.Camera` API, the `android.hardware.camera2` API, and third-party libraries that simplify those APIs (e.g., Fotoapparat, CameraKit-Android).

> i plan to use other camera activity to take the picture

If by "other camera activity", you mean a third-party camera app (e.g., via `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`), that will be difficult and unreliable. At best, you could try to use a `content` `Uri` pointing to a `ContentProvider` that you write that only holds onto written streams in memory. I would expect you to run out of heap space. Plus, not all camera apps will support a `content` `Uri` for `EXTRA_OUTPUT` (though they should).